# How can call a method contain session from Other Controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 Controller: OpsLinkController vs OpsController

In OpsLinkController I want call to a method in OpsController

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //
            OpsController c = new OpsController();
            int i = c.Test();
            return View();
        }
```

in OpsController i have method

```
public int Test()
        {
            Session["A"] = 1;
            // Do som thing here
            return (int)Session["A"];
        }
```

It throw an exception: "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

But when we can call by ajax from View Index, it OK:

```
$.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
               // type: "POST",
                url: "/Ops/Test",
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                err: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
```

result: 1
Why we can excute method Test by ajax, but can't excute from OpsLinkController?

How can we access method Test from OpsLinkController?

Comment: Use redirect to switch from first controller to another. Place `Test` method execution on `OpsController` action method (e.g. `Index`) before returning view & use `RedirectToAction("Index", "Ops")` from `OpsLinkController.Index()`  to redirect.

Comment: Why is your controller newing up another controller? This is certainly not a good practice. If you have functionality that is common to multiple controllers, it should probably be in a service that is injected into each of those controllers, and the runtime data (session state params) should be passed in as method parameters to the service. You should never need to refer to session state outside of the current action method.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer the question: How can we access method Test from OpsLinkController?

You can't call Test from OpsLinkController because session of OpsController is not existed in this case.

1 Session created when the page start, when you construction OpsController in OpsLinkController

```
OpsController c = new OpsController();
            int i = c.Test();
```

Session has not created yes.

Answer the question: Why we can execute method Test by ajax?

In ajax you has been call to OpsController it mean an Session of OpsController will be created.

```
url: "/Ops/Test",
```

=> it Ok,

But if your url like this:

```
url: "/OpsLink /Test",
```

The error will be throw "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"